# How to remove the border around the polygons with ggplot with NA in the legend

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, legend, na

I have a map with gradient and `NA` values both in the map and in the legend. The result of creating a map is as follows.

```
library(ggplot)
map       = map_data("world")
map$value <- setNames(sample(-50:50, length(unique(map$region)), TRUE), 
                      unique(map$region))[map$region]
map[map$region == "Russia", "value"] <- NA

p2 = ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = map, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill= value, color = "")) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="brown3", mid="cornsilk1", high="turquoise4",
                       limits=c(-50, 50), na.value="black") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=NA) +              
  guides(colour = guide_legend("No data", override.aes =list(colour="black")))
```

[image: NA is in the legend but with borders]

Now, I want to remove the borders around the polygons. As I remove the `color = ""` in `geom_plogyon`, the borders around the polygons are removed but the `NA` values box in legend is removed as well.

```
p2 = ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = map, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill= value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="brown3", mid="cornsilk1", high="turquoise4",
                       limits=c(-50, 50), na.value="black") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=NA) +              
  guides(colour = guide_legend("No data", override.aes =list(colour="black")))
```

[image: NA disappears from the legend]

As you can see, `NA` disappears from the legend as I remove the borders. How can I remove the borders around the polygons while keeping `NA` values in the legend?

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying `scale_colour_manual(values = NA)`. By default, `NA` values are plotted in a medium gray color, like the borders in your example. We can instead specify `scale_colour_manual(values = 'transparent')`. Note that `color = ''` must appear somewhere in `aes()`, or `scale_color_manual` won't be activated and the custom "No data" legend won't be shown.

```
p2 = ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = map, aes(long, lat, group = group, fill= value, color = '')) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="brown3", mid="cornsilk1", high="turquoise4",
                       limits=c(-50, 50), na.value="black") +
  scale_colour_manual(values='transparent') +              
  guides(colour = guide_legend("No data", override.aes =list(colour="black")))
```

[image]